# Finding k-smallest eigen values and its corresponding eigen vector for large matrix

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

For a symmetric sparse square matrix of size 300,000*300,000, what is best way to find 10 smallest Eigenvalues and its corresponding Eigenvectors within an hours or so in any language or packages.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/yixuan/spectra (never tried it myself, but this seems to be exactly what you need)

Comment: @chtz Thanks for help but it seems like it is for K largest eigenvalues or all. Instead of computing all eigenvalues, I just need K smallest eigenvalues and its corresponding vectors.

Comment: According to the docu, it also supports computing the eigenvalues closest to 0: https://github.com/yixuan/spectra#shift-and-invert-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lanczos algorithm, which operates on a Hermitian matrix, is one good way to find the lowest and greatest eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors.  Note that a real symmetric matrix is by definition Hermitian.  Lanczos requires `O(N)` storage and also roughly `O(N)` time to evaluate the extreme eigenvalues/eigenvectors.  This contrasts with brute force diagonalization which requires `O(N^2)` storage and `O(N^3)` running time.  For this reason, the Lanczos algorithm made possible approximate solutions to many problems which previously were not computationally feasible.

[Here is a useful link](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~bai/ET/lanczos_methods/lanczos_methods.html) to a UC Davis site, which lists implementations of Lanczos in a number of languages/packages, including FORTRAN, C/C++, and MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect. My matrix is a Laplace matrix of a graph. When I try to find k smallest Eigen values, it gives me the error : "First input matrix is singular. The shift 0 is an eigenvalue. Consider using a nonzero
numeric value for sigma". Is there any way around to compute k-smallest eigen values in this case.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps your data is such that it won't work well with Lanczos.

Comment: Somehow "It works perfect", and "it gives me the error [...]" contradict each other. Did you try a nonzero value for sigma as the error suggests?

Comment: @chtz sigma corresponds to the different choice of eigenvalues. For sigma = 'sm' i.e. sigma = 0 corresponds to "Smallest magnitude", which is interested. It is working for other value of sigma very fast.

Comment: @bemma, yes I understand that. Did you try, e.g., `1e-6` or `-1e-6`? (no idea how close to zero your EVs are)

Comment: @chtz Thanks, with 1e-6 no error comes up taking bit longer than k largest.